# Could anyone explain these XSS test strings?

Tags: javascript, xss

recently I found this tutorial about XSS and web application security -> https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Locator

At the start there are some strings to inject in order to test that a site is vulnerable to xss or not. These strings are:

```
';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";
alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//--
></SCRIPT>">'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>
```

and

```
'';!--"<XSS>=&{()}
```

I know the basic concepts of XSS, but here I can't understand why there's that repetition of 'alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))' in the first string and why those *//';*   *//";*   *//-->* comments are needed for (do they mean something special when used in such a way whilesearching for xss bugs?).
And in the second string, what is the purpose of the &{()} sequence?

Could anyone exlain me with **concrete examples** how this two strings should work in order to retrieve an xss bug inside a web app? Cause on the site I linked no explanation is given...

Comment: 88,83,83 is just "XSS". The point is to try to break out of various quotes, tags, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know what the alert is supposed to do, what I would like to understand is **how** this 'break out of various quotes, tags, etc.' works, could you explain me it please, if you know it?

Comment: If you rendered that string on a client what would it look like? What would it look like if it was in a tag? Rendered as part of JS code? Etc. Why not just try taking that string and rendering it in all the ways you can think of, without escaping it?

Comment: At the moment I do not have a laptop to try it, but sure I will as soon as possible when I come home, it is curiosity and the desire to understand immediately that prompted me to write this question, cause if someone who just tested it could explain it in an understandable way it will be a good cheat sheet for all the SO community that will came across the same issue, so I try to test it myself but I will still wait you or someone else to answer in a simple and complete way that could immediately help us understand the topic. Anyway thank you!

Comment: Do it in your head: think about how you render, and what might happen. There are many places that explain this with concrete examples, I'm not convinced we need a comprehensive list here. For example, http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/xss-attack-examples/

Answer (score 28):

This looks like it's trying several different injections, so I'll try and break them down one at a time:

#### The First Injection

```
';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//
```

This injection attempts to terminate a JavaScript string literal (using `'`), then terminate the statement (with `;`) and makes a call to `alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))` which will cause a popup box containing "XSS".  The following `//` is an attempt to "comment out" the rest of the statement, so that a syntax error will not occur and the script will execute.

#### The Second Injection

```
";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//
```

Like the first injection, but it uses `"` in an attempt to terminate a JavaScript string literal.

#### The Third Injection

```
--></SCRIPT>">'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>
```

This attempts to do the following things:

1. Terminate an HTML (or XML) comment (with `-->`)
2. Terminate an existing `<SCRIPT>` tag using `</SCRIPT>`

   - This is done to prevent the injected script causing a syntax error, which would prevent the injected script from executing.
3. Terminate an HTML attribute and tag, using `">`
4. Terminate an HTML attribute and tag, using `'>`
5. Inject JavaScript using `<SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>`

#### The Fourth Injection

```
'';!--"<XSS>=&{()}
```

This is a common string used to test what, if any, filters and/or encoding are being used on user input.  Typically, the source of the page after this injection will contain either `&lt;XSS` or `<XSS`.  If the second is found, the application is most likely not filtering user input (as it allowed the addition of an arbitrary tag) and is likely vulnerable to XSS.

---

To answer your more direct questions:

> why there's that repetition of 'alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))'

This is a common "Proof of Concept" function, that will cause a popup box to appear containing "XSS".  If this occurs, the injected JavaScript was executed.

> why there's that repetition of 'alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))' in the first string and why those //'; //"; //-->

These are used to prevent syntax errors, which can cause the injected JavaScript to fail to execute.