# XSS vulnerability locator

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

I was reading an article about XSS filter evasion at https://www.owasp.org. One of the ways described in the article to locate a vulnerability was to try injecting the following:

```html
'';!--"<XSS>=&{()}
```

Then, if there is a  tag in the document source, opposed to <XSS>, the site is vulnerable to XSS. Why does the snippet above bypass some XSS and escaping filters?

Comment: What do you mean by "injecting"? Where and how?

Comment: input field, for example

Comment: What is the server side language that is supposedly vulnerable to this? Your question needs more detail and the link doesn't go to the article you mentioned.

Comment: Partial duplicate: [Could anyone explain these XSS test strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461418/could-anyone-explain-these-xss-test-strings)

Comment: Missing link to source where you found this. The text there ought to explain what this does, and if not, we could have contributed  that because OWASP pages are typically wikis.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet tries to break free from attributes and tags, additionally it embeds its own tag . You should look for the disappearance of  or malformed HTML in the GUI or errors in JavaScript.

Comment: It doesn't break free, it just lets you see if those characters get encoded in the page response.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the snippet above bypass some XSS and escaping filters?

It does not. What makes you think it should? What does the text say where you found this?

What this allows you to do, is check in the HTTP response if characters are being returned without encoding. There is no built-in `<XSS>` tag, so this will never run or trigger anything, those three letters are just to find your payload back again in the middle of a bunch of other contents, while also being a valid tag such that you notice when a filter would not remove `<>` but would remove `<tag>`.

A bypass injection looks more like this:

```
';window['ale'+'rt'](window['doc'+'ument']['dom'+'ain']);//
```

Which avoids using words such as 'alert' literally, because some stupid filters might block that (even though an attacker has no use for the alert function: it doesn't allow you to steal any data or so, so this rather annoys white hat testers compared to real attackers...).